# How to properly use Retrofit to call a JSON API in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, serialization, android-jetpack-compose, retrofit2

I've tried following several tutorials on calling an API and receiving a JSON response in Kotlin, and this is what I have so far:

```
interface APIService {
    @GET("cursor/popular/10")
    fun listRepos(): Call<Any?>
    // @Path("user") user: String?
}

fun getURL(url: String): Call<Any?>  {
    val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(url)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .build()

    val service = retrofit.create(APIService::class.java)

    val data: Call<Any?> = service.listRepos()

    Log.d("PRINT_JSON_HERE", "HERE: ${data}")

    return data
}
```

When I call `getURL("api_here")` nothing happens, no error either.

Just wondering what I am doing wrong. I know it says the `data class` is "Any" but when I start getting a response I'll replace it with a proper data class.

This code is inside a `class/ViewModel()`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score -1):

Api call returns a response and you need to implement onResponse and onFailure override method in your program after

```
val service = retrofit.create(APIService::class.java)
```

this put this code

```
service.enqueue(object : Callback<List<userItem>> {

        override fun onResponse(
            call : Call<List<userItem>>,
            response: Response<List<userItem>>
        ) {

        var data = response.body()

        Log.d("data", data.toString)
    }

        override fun onFailure(call : Call<List<userItem>> , t : Throwable) {
            "print toast if an error occurred"
        }

        )}


    }

    }
```

in this code **userItem** is a data class that can get data from the api.

I hope this can help you.

):

Comment: This doesn't work, `service` is expecting `Call<Any?>` but receiving `APIService` instead, your solution doesn't take that into consideration, could you show me how to update my existing code so yours works please?